# Drawing mitochondria

Tags: tikz-styles

Could someone give me a code to plot a mitochondrion like the picture below, or something similar. The pie plot is not necessary.
I'm a beginner of tikz and I tried some method and googled a lot but whit no lucky. Many thanks for your kind help.

[image: mitochondria]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Specifically, I assume if you combined some of the work from [Confused about TikZ \draw\[rotate=angle\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47950) and [Package for pie charts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5718), you'd have a much more focused question.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I really need more practice, both for asking questions and writing tikz code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple mitochondrion (add more intermediate control points):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{153,51,51}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{228,154,74}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[mypurple!80,draw=mypurple!70!black,line width=3pt]
  (0,0) to[out=210,in=90] 
  (-2,-5) to[out=270,in=170] 
  (2,-10) to[out=-10,in=300] 
  (4,-3) to[out=120,in=30] 
  (0,0);
\filldraw[mybrown!70,draw=mybrown!60!black,line width=1pt]
  ([shift={(0pt,-10pt)}]0,0) to[out=210,in=90]
  ([shift={(10pt,30pt)}]-2,-5) .. controls ++(5cm,10pt) and ++(5cm,20pt) ..
  ([shift={(10pt,0pt)}]-2,-5) to[out=270,in=130] 
  ([shift={(0pt,10pt)}]-0.8,-8) .. controls ++(3cm,20pt) .. 
  ([shift={(0pt,-10pt)}]-0.3,-8) to[out=300,in=270,looseness=1.45]
  (4.25,-7) .. controls ++(-2cm,10pt) and ++(-50pt,0pt) ..
  ([shift={(0pt,15pt)}]4.25,-7)
  to[out=80,in=300] 
  ([shift={(-10pt,10pt)}]3.8,-3)  .. controls ++(-4cm,10pt) and ++(-50pt,0pt) ..
  ([shift={(-10pt,30pt)}]3.3,-3) to[out=120,in=30] 
  ([shift={(0pt,-10pt)}]0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much, all your guys are so  great and I love tikz.